# Shellcheck complains that I should not to read and write the same file in the same pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, shellcheck

[ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) show the following error for this line of code:

```
printf '%d' $(($(< "$1") + 1)) > "$1"
```

[Make sure not to read and write the same file in the same pipeline](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2094)

Is this really a problem? Could reading and writing the same file result in a race condition?

Comment: Note that `$(<file)` construct only work in `bash`, `zsh` and `ksh` variants.

Comment: See also this [Warning regarding ‘>’](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216#186126 "What are the shell’s control and redirection operators?").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, reading and writing from the same file in parallel could result in a race condition. An input and an output redirection for the same file on the same command would truncate the file before starting to read it.

But no, this isn't what's happening here. It's a false positive in Shellcheck. Here the redirection is inside an arithmetic expression. All substitutions (arithmetic, variable, command, as well as splitting and globbing) are performed before redirections are executed. So at the time `> "$1"` opens the file, the reading bit is finished.

Comment: Note that it would be a different matter in `(printf '%d' $(($(< "$1") + 1))) > "$1"`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a problem, you can never read and write from/to the same pipe. Think of it this way: writing a file would set it to start as empty, and then reading from it would not yield anything.

Comment: I was under the impression that `$(< "$1")` would read the file as a whole, no?

Comment: Actually, you're right indeed. Sorry, I glossed over your ``$(< "$1" )`` syntax which indeed delegates it to a subshell, so the pipe is closed before output starts. It works and the syntax checker is wrong.

Comment: This problem is the exact reason the `sponge` utility was invented. It will be in your moreutils package on most Linux distributions.