# Inconsistent behavior when modifying file in-place with cat, sort, tee, and pipes

Tags: bash, pipe, sort, cat, tee

**Situation**: When using the following command:

```
cat foo | sort | tee foo
```

where `foo` is a text file of multiple lines, the outcome is not consistent. The two outcomes I've observed are:

1. The file is sorted, and the sorted contents are printed to stdout.
2. The file is emptied, and nothing is printed.

**Question**: Why does this happen?

P.S. I realize that `sort` has a `-o` option on my system.

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409896/22222) from the duplicate explains what is happening here.

Comment: Also related:  [Shellcheck complains that I should not read and write the same file in the same pipeline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/231832/80216), [Do redirection operators always open file descriptors in parallel?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79036/80216), and [Warning regarding ‘‘>’’](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216#186126).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a race condition. You start two commands (on both sides of the pipeline) which both try to access the same file in different ways (read vs. erase). The result is chance.

```
cat foo | sort | ( tee foo.new; mv foo.new foo)
```