# "Make sure not to read and write the same file in the same pipeline"

Tags: bash, shellcheck

shellcheck reports:

```
echo -e "blah/blah\n$(cat "$tmpdir"/"$filename".jpdf)" > "$tmpdir"/"$filename".jpdf
                          ^-- SC2094: Make sure not to read and write the same file in the same pipeline.
                                                         ^-- SC2094: Make sure not to read and write the same file in the same pipeline.
```

The command is intended to insert a line `blah/blah` at the beginning of a file `"$tmpdir"/"$filename".jpdf`.

What does "Make sure not to read and write the same file in the same pipeline" mean?

What shall I do instead?

Thanks.

Comment: [Warning regarding ‘‘>’’](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216#186126 "What are the shell's control and redirection operators?").

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/231832/674

Answer (score 8):

As the other answers pointed out, it is warning you that reading from and writing to the same file will erase the file. The reason is that `>` causes the file to be truncated before input is finished.

You have two options,

1. Use `sponge` from the `moreutils` package. `sponge` ensures that the input is fully consumed before it is piped to the next command.

   Instead of

   ```
   command "$file" > "$file"
   ```

   do

   ```
   command "$file" | sponge "$file"
   ```
2. Redirect output to another file and rename afterwards.

   Like this

   ```
   command "$file" > "$file2" && mv "$file2" "$file"
   ```

Regarding your specific question: prepending 'blah/blah' to the file, you can use `sed` if it supports the `-i` option. Take `GNU` `sed` as an example:

```
sed '1i\
blah/blah' -i "$file"
```

Answer (score 1):

It means exactly what it says in the most literal sense possible. What this command is actually doing is overwriting the file `$tmpdir/$filename.jpdf` with only the single line being echo'ed. The shell will see the redirect, then truncate that file and open it for writing, and only then will it begin to perform the commands to generate its (new) contents. What you should do instead is write the new contents to a different file, then copy the new file over to the old name in a second command.

Answer (score 1):

Lets type an equivalent simpler command line:

```
cat file > file
```

If file contains data it will be erased, lets try:

```
$ echo "content of file" > file
$ cat file
content of file

$ cat file > file

$ cat file
                     # empty file.
```

The shell process redirections before executing the command.
On processing `>file`, it opens `file` for writing truncating it.
After that, the file is empty.
The command `cat` does the cat of an empty file, nothing gets written.